# Why say "à mainte et mainte reprises" instead of "à maintes et maintes reprises"?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

> Il serait alors plus judicieux d'éviter de perpétuer une expression qui n'a plus aucune raison d'exister dans un monde où les personnes non pourvues de testicules ont déjà clairement démontré **à mainte et mainte reprises** leur courage et leur force.

This seems to be in stark contrast to the following two cases where we use "maintes" in the plural:

> C'est l'une des choses dont j'ai déjà **maintes fois** entendues parler.
>
> Nous avons assisté **à maintes reprises** à ce spectacle lamentable de grands patrons augmentant de façon scandaleuse leur salaire et favorisant plus que de raison les actionnaires.

Answer (score 1):

*[Mainte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mainte)* originally means more than one. It can be used at the singular to mean just that, or at the plural to mean "several times more than one", i.e. "a lot".

Strictly speaking, *mainte et mainte* means more than two and *maintes et maintes* means "a large number" but now both are synonyms. The former is outdated.